# How to resolve Unresolved reference:kotlinx error when using coroutines

Tags: kotlin

I have started learning Kotlin coroutines.I implemented a basic coroutine program but its is not working.I even added the dependency but still the code is not working.Could some one help in this?

in build.gradle looks as below:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.30'
    ext.kotlin_gradle_plugin_version = '1.3.0'
    ext.kotlinx_coroutines = '1.0.0'

    repositories {
        maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlin-eap" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.2.1")
    }
    }
plugins {
    id 'java'
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.30"
}

group 'Test2.project'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
```

code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) 
{
    println("hello")
}
```

Comment: try moving dependencies out of `buildscript` block

Comment: How is it "not working":? What does your code do now and what should it do?

Comment: by moving dependencies out of buildscipt block It is still  not working

Comment: The expected output is to print hello without having any error when we import coroutines.